# I am seeing the empty source directory being created in the destination folder along with the file while using Copy-item command in Powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

```
$InputFile = "C:\InfoWorkflows.txt"

$fileText = Get-Content $InputFile

foreach ($LineText in $fileText){
    echo "LineText is $LineText"
    $containsWord = $LineText | %{$_ -match "test_control.xml"}
    if($containsWord -eq $false)
    {
        $SplitText = $LineText -split' '
        $Change = $SplitText[0]
        $fileName = $SplitText[1]
        echo "fileName is $fileName"
        echo "Copy-Item -Path C:\mb\INFO\$fileName -Destination C:\BackOrder\INFOT"
    }
}
```

In the destination folder C:\BackOrder\INFOT, I am able to see the files other than "test_Control.xml" on executing the PS which are mentioned in the inputFile and also a blank Folder (INFO) is being created from Source Path for which I never provided any instruction.Can someone look into it and help me?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're actually trying to do. Please do not use aliasses (especially not in forums and in scripts).  You may explain the purpose of your script and post some example data. You might (re-)read the help topic [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: your code does not make any directories, nor does it make any files. [*grin*] so ... where is the code that DOES make the unwanted directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have does not check for the existance of the output folder 'C:\BackOrder\INFOT', nor does it check if the 'C:\mb\INFO\$fileName' exists.
Other than that, I don't see why you are stringyfying the `Copy-Item` cmdlet..

Another thing is that you use the regex `-match` operator on a filename containing a period (`.`) character without escaping it. In Regex, the dot has a special meaning, namely 'any character.'

The code below uses the String object method `.Contains` to filter for strings that do not contain "test_control.xml" in a `Where-Object{}` clause. In the code comment you can read how to use `[Regex]::Escape()` if you do want to keep using `-match`.

```
$InputFile = 'C:\InfoWorkflows.txt'
$OutputDir = 'C:\BackOrder\INFOT'

# test if output folder exists and if not create it first
if (!(Test-Path -Path $OutputDir -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Host "Creating folder $OutputDir"
    $null = New-Item -Path $OutputDir -ItemType Directory
}
# read the input file as string array and filter the lines that do not contain "test_control.xml")
# if you want to do that with the regex -match operator, you should escape it first:
#   [Regex]::Escape("test_control.xml")  --> "test_control\.xml"
$fileText  = Get-Content $InputFile | Where-Object { !$_.Contains("test_control.xml") } | ForEach-Object {
    $fileName = ($_ -split ' ')[1]
    Write-Host "FileName is $fileName"
    # combine the path and file name for the file to copy
    $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path 'C:\mb\INFO' -ChildPath $fileName
    if (Test-Path -Path $sourceFile -PathType Leaf) {
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $OutputDir
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "File '$sourceFile' could not be found."
    }
}
```

Hope that helps